# Magento 2: Which event fires when I reorder from admin side?

Tags: admin, orders, event-observer, reorder

I have activated reorder on my magento 2 site. Now I want a event which can catch reorder both in frontend and backend (admin). I am using "**controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_reorder**" for my front end which is working perfectly fine but I want to catch reorder on the backend as well. Can anyone tell me which event to use for backend as "**controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder**" is not working for backend?

Here is my code:

**Event file**
app/code/VoltLighting/OrderInfo/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_reorder">
    <observer name="admin_reorder_observer" instance="VoltLighting\OrderInfo\Observer\AdminReorder" />
</event>

<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <observer name="admin_order_observer" instance="VoltLighting\OrderInfo\Observer\AdminOrder" />
</event>
```

**Observer file**
app/code/VoltLighting/OrderInfo/Observer/AdminReorder.php

```
<?php
namespace VoltLighting\OrderInfo\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AdminReorder implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order= $observer->getEvent();

        echo "hello world";
        exit;
      
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly you would want to achieve with the event.? as such there might be other events that may fulfill your requirement by placing the event in the global events.xml file for the module i.e vendor/module/etc/events.xml which will work for both front and backend.

Comment: I want to find out whether my order is reorder or not and get the original order ID along with the products associated with my original order and store it in a custom table.

Comment: sales_order_create_reorder should really cover both frontend and backend reordering as they use the same models for both frontend and backend

Comment: I tried sales_order_create_reorder and refereshed my cache. It didn't work :(

Comment: Try observing sales_convert_order_to_quote. This fires when converting a previous order into a new quote ... aka preparing to reorder. You will probably need to set some sort of flag on the quote and then at the time the quote converts to an order, pass the flag. Something like $quote->setData('is_reorder', true). The admin panel ordering process is a bit different than the frontend.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the admin reorder controller, you will see `$this->_getOrderCreateModel()->initFromOrder($order);`. The observer event I advised you of in the comment above is dispatched inside of the initFromOrder function

Comment: @ShawnAbramson Thanks, sales_convert_order_to_quote worked. Now I need original order id from this event which I can save it into my custom table.

Comment: "sales_convert_order_to_quote" this event is working, I was able to do what I wanted. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Can I present that as the official answer and you will accept?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson sure you can present it.

Comment: I have posted my official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observer the sales_convert_order_to_quote event. This fires when converting a previous order into a new quote ... aka preparing to reorder.

You will probably need to set some sort of flag on the quote and then at the time the quote converts to an order, pass the flag. Something like $quote->setData('is_reorder', true). The admin panel ordering process is a bit different than the frontend.

If you look at the admin reorder controller, you will see `$this->_getOrderCreateModel()->initFromOrder($order);`. The observer event mentioned above is dispatched inside of the initFromOrder function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `sales_order_place_after` event will be the one you want to hook into.

Answer (score 0):

I think `adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer` event will be use. path is here`vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Reorder/Renderer/Action.php`

Comment: I already tried "adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer" event, this one is not working.